# Adding Javascript file to MVC Project in VS 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have migrated my project from VS 2017 to VS 2022,
And I have a strange problem:

When attempting to add a new `.JS` file to the `scripts` folder
I don't have the option to select .`JS` file in the "Add New Item" menu (via right-click on scripts folder), only `.TS` or `.JSON`:

[image]

Tried "playing" with it and searching but did not find any solution.
can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: I have several times more templates in VS2022. Try to use VS installer and select javascsript and typescript support inside of  an individual components tab. But as a matter of fact you can add any file - class for example and change an extension to .js

Comment: Ended up adding a text file and changing it to .js, wonder why it`s like that on VS2022...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This depends on one thing that is if you installed all required modules for Visual Studio 2022.

The basic thing here is to **Right-Click** on any directory/folder in the Solution Explorer window, Select Add and then New Item. **You then click on the Language you are programming in**. Note: if you don't click this folder, the options you may see would be only for the selected folder.

See below images...
[image: Adding a JS file]

[image: Where the file is added.]